# Error 524 A timeout occurred | Wordpress | Cloudflare

Tags: php, wordpress, cloudflare

I am getting 524 error When i access my website. I am using CDN cloudflare.

Anyone suggest me how to fix it.

Attach screenshot.[Error Screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wazd8.png)

Pls tell me step by step I am not a tech guy, I don't have a technical knowldege

Comment: This may be a solution: [stackoverflow - question - cloudflare-524](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37381923/cloudflare-524-error-with-ajax?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C95.7097)

Answer (score -2):

Please check activity what you did that make site down
Ask server to restore website from backup
as
A 524 error occurred when something go wrong with database

I got same problem when i delete one user from admin and site went down

Answer (score -3):

**A 524 error states that CloudFlare was able to make a TCP connection to the origin, but the origin did not reply with a HTTP response before the connection timed out. This means that CloudFlare is able to make a network connection to the origin server, but the origin server took too long to respond to the request.**

See Attached Here,

[image]

Comment: You just copy and paste hare Dear, I have read this. I m asking step by step solution, Thank in advance